# Why Electron App doesn't load VueJS in Windows?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

I built a desktop app with electron and I used VueJS (along with Firebase) for all the front end, now when I compile it and run the `.exe` on windows **VueJS** is not being loaded at all, the div with "app" id is not showing, so alll the app is not showing, even though the console is not showing any error.

It is able to load related HTML files, but I can't find a way to make it load the app made through VueJS. In dev mode it works like a charm, I run the app through Vue-cli and then run electron in another terminal.

Here's the code in main.js related to electron:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

let url
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'DEV') {
  url = 'http://localhost:8080/#/'

} else {
url = `file://${process.cwd()}/resources/app/public/index.html`
}

app.on('ready', () => {
  let window = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  window.loadURL(url)
})
```

And the main.js related to VueJS:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import ArgonDashboard from './plugins/argon-dashboard'
window.Event = new Vue();
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(ArgonDashboard)
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

I spent more than a day looking for a solution and I can't find any, thank's for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you building it but I guess that you not pointing to `index.html` properly. Try to change it to something like this:

```
const url = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'DEV' ? `http://localhost:8080/#/` : `file://${__dirname}/index.html`
```

**EDIT:**
Also I suggest you to use a vue/electron [boilerplate](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue)